# Where can I find Protobuf definitions for Datastore Admin v1 API?

Tags: java, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, protocol-buffers, datastore-admin

I'm trying to use the Datastore Admin API v1 that was recently announced GA and wanted to wonder where can I find protobufs for the related API?

I have found some protobufs within the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/datastore) repository, but there are only protobufs for the Datastore Admin API v1beta1 that is already deprecated.

Moreover, I wanted to ask if anyone knows why Admin API protos are not published in Maven Central?

The general Datastore API protos [are](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api.grpc/proto-google-cloud-datastore-v1).

Answer (score 3):

Oops.

In the meantime, you can take that existing proto and change one line:

From:
`package google.datastore.admin.v1beta1;`

To:
`package google.datastore.admin.v1;`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Dan, I have already done that, but it is not a clean solution...

I'd also like to wonder if there are any plans to create Java wrapper around Datastore admin API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like protobuf definitions for the Admin API are now available through the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/tree/master/google/datastore/admin/v1) repository.

But they are not yet published to the Maven Central.